# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend') in jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am using node version: v20.3.1 and jest version: 29.7.0, while running test cases getting typeError and i dont know how to solve it

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src/__test__"],
 
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  },

 
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"],

  testMatch: ["**/*.test.(js|jsx)"],
  // testRegex: "(/__test__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.jsx?$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "tsx", "ts", "json", "node"],
  snapshotSerializers: ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"],
  reporters: ["default", "jest-junit"],

  //i don't need to test static JSX in the icons folder. So, exclude those
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules", "src/lang"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ".+\\/(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$":
      "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/files",
  },
};
```

and setupTest.js

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/jest-globals";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
```

test cases:

```
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Login } from "../pages/Login/Login";

describe("Testing Login Component", () => {
  it("renders without errors", () => {
    render(<Login />);
    // Check that the component renders without errors
    expect(screen.getByText("Login")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

error:
FAIL  src/**test**/Login.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')

  1 | // jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
  2 | // allows you to do things like:
> 3 | // expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i);
    | ^
  4 | // learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
  5 | // In your own jest-setup.js
  6 | import "@testing-library/jest-dom/jest-globals";

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom/dist/jest-globals.js:18:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/setupTests.js:3:1)
```

i want to to perform unit test using jest but in @latest version there is some issue
i don't know hoe to fix, i tried multiple solutions but none of them work for me

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution, I've encountered the same problem in solidjs